# Copying styles from a range to another range?

Tags: python, excel, performance, openpyxl

I have an excel file that I'm using as a template where I add information in as it's needed.

I have special styles and merges that need to be done on a couple of ranges of cells, but the way I'm doing it right now (bruteforcing it) is very slow when there is a lot of data.

Is there a way I could be doing this better?

```
for a in xrange(1, len(plans)):
offset = 3 * a

# Create blank templates for plans
for x in xrange(5, 549):
  first_col_cell = recommended.cell(row=x, column=4)
  second_col_cell = recommended.cell(row=x, column=5)
  third_col_cell = recommended.cell(row=x, column=6)

  new_first_col_cell = recommended.cell(row=x, column=4 + offset)
  new_second_col_cell = recommended.cell(row=x, column=5 + offset)
  new_third_col_cell = recommended.cell(row=x, column=6 + offset)

  if third_col_cell.has_style and x != 42:
    new_third_col_cell.font = copy(third_col_cell.font)
    new_third_col_cell.border = copy(third_col_cell.border)
    new_third_col_cell.fill = copy(third_col_cell.fill)
    new_third_col_cell.number_format = copy(third_col_cell.number_format)
    new_third_col_cell.protection = copy(third_col_cell.protection)
    new_third_col_cell.alignment = copy(third_col_cell.alignment)
    new_third_col_cell.value = copy(third_col_cell.value)

  if second_col_cell.has_style and x != 42:
    new_second_col_cell.font = copy(second_col_cell.font)
    new_second_col_cell.border = copy(second_col_cell.border)
    new_second_col_cell.fill = copy(second_col_cell.fill)
    new_second_col_cell.number_format = copy(second_col_cell.number_format)
    new_second_col_cell.protection = copy(second_col_cell.protection)
    new_second_col_cell.alignment = copy(second_col_cell.alignment)
    new_second_col_cell.value = copy(second_col_cell.value)

  if first_col_cell.has_style and x != 42:
    new_first_col_cell.font = copy(first_col_cell.font)
    new_first_col_cell.border = copy(first_col_cell.border)
    new_first_col_cell.fill = copy(first_col_cell.fill)
    new_first_col_cell.number_format = copy(first_col_cell.number_format)
    new_first_col_cell.protection = copy(first_col_cell.protection)
    new_first_col_cell.alignment = copy(first_col_cell.alignment)
    new_first_col_cell.value = copy(first_col_cell.value)

  if (x >= 6 and x <= 33) or x == 36 or x == 41 or x == 44:
    recommended.merge_cells(start_row=x, start_column=4 + offset, end_row=x, end_column=6 + offset)

    if first_col_cell.has_style:
      recommended_merge = colnum_string(4 + offset) + str(x) + ':' + colnum_string(6 + offset) + str(x)
      style_border(recommended, recommended_merge, border)
      second_col_cell.border = copy(first_col_cell.border)
      third_col_cell.border = copy(first_col_cell.border)
```

Here's the calnum_string function too, in case that's needed:

```
def colnum_string(n):
  div=n
  string=""
  while div>0:
    module=(div-1)%26
    string=chr(65+module)+string
    div=int((div-module)/26)
  return string
```

Comment: 100 plans needs ~5 min on my environment. How slow is yours?

Comment: @stovfl, pretty close to that. Embarrassingly slow. I need to figure out a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **workload** are to copy the six styles, e.g.
    `new_third_col_cell.font = copy(third_col_cell.font)`

Try to copy only the style reference, instead of assigning new styles, for instance

```
target_cell._style = copy(source_cell._style)
```

You can save ~10 %, per Style, **if not all** Styles are are used in all cells.
Copy only used styles, for instance:

```
if source_cell._style.fontId: target_cell.font = copy(s_cell.font)
...
```

Besides this, consider to *slim* your code, for instance:

```
def copy_style(s_cell, t_cell):
    ...

def merge_cells(ws, row, offset, columns_456):
    ...

def main(recommended, plans):
    column_456 = [4,5,6]

    for a in xrange(1, len(plans)):
        offset = 3 * a

        # Create blank templates for plans
        for x in xrange(5, 549):
            if x != 42:
              for column in column_456:
                  cell = recommended.cell(row=x, column=column)
                  if cell.has_style:
                      copy_style(cell, recommended.cell(row=x, column=column+offset))

            if (x >= 6 and x <= 33) or x == 36 or x == 41 or x == 44:
                merge_cells(recommended, x, offset, column_456)
```

Comment: `target_cell._style = copy(source_cell._style)` did the trick. That reduced the time by a huge factor. Thank you!

Comment: target_cell._style = copy(source_cell._style) did the magic.... thanks