# Iterate over Worksheets, Rows, Columns

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to print all data (all rows) of a specific column in python using `openpyxl` I am working in this way;

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('----------/dataset.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active  
for i in sheet:
   print(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)
```

But it gives

> if row < 1 or column < 1:
>   TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int()

Because i am iterating in `row=i`. If I use `sheet.cell(row=4, column=2).value` it print the value of cell. But how can I iterate over all document?

**Edit 1**

On some research, it is found that data can be get using Sheet Name. The `Sheet 1` exists in the `.xlsx` file but its data is not printing. Any problem in this code?

```
workbook = load_workbook('---------------/dataset.xlsx')
print(workbook.get_sheet_names())
worksheet =workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
c=2
for i in worksheet: 
    d = worksheet.cell(row=c, column=2)
    if(d.value is None):
        return
    else:
        print(d.value)
    c=c+1
```

Comment: Read the Answer from this Question to get a hint how it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777213/how-do-i-use-openpyxl-and-still-maintain-oop-structure

Comment: @stovfl It is not working.

Comment: to iterate over all the rows you can use `iter_rows` like `sheet.iter_rows(row_offset=1)`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Read the [OpenPyXL Documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io)

Iteration over all `worksheets` in a `workbook`, for instance:

```
for n, sheet in enumerate(wb.worksheets):
    print('Sheet Index:[{}], Title:{}'.format(n, sheet.title))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Sheet Index:[0], Title: Sheet    
> Sheet Index:[1], Title: Sheet1    
> Sheet Index:[2], Title: Sheet2
> ```

---

Iteration over all `rows` and `columns` in **one** Worksheet:

```
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')

for row_cells in worksheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row_cells:
       print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value) )
```

**Output**:

```
<Cell Sheet.A1>: cell.value=²234
<Cell Sheet.B1>: cell.value=12.5
<Cell Sheet.C1>: cell.value=C1
<Cell Sheet.D1>: cell.value=D1
<Cell Sheet.A2>: cell.value=1234
<Cell Sheet.B2>: cell.value=8.2
<Cell Sheet.C2>: cell.value=C2
<Cell Sheet.D2>: cell.value=D2
```

---

Iteration over all `columns` of **one** `row`, for instance `row==2`:

```
for row_cells in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=2):
    for cell in row_cells:
        print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value) )
```

**Output**:

```
<Cell Sheet.A2>: cell.value=1234  
<Cell Sheet.B2>: cell.value=8.2  
<Cell Sheet.C2>: cell.value=C2  
<Cell Sheet.D2>: cell.value=D2
```

---

Iteration over **all** `rows`, only `column` **2**:

```
for col_cells in worksheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=2):
    for cell in col_cells:
        print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value))
```

**Output**:

```
<Cell Sheet.B1>: cell.value=12.5
<Cell Sheet.B2>: cell.value=8.2
<Cell Sheet.B3>: cell.value=9.8
<Cell Sheet.B4>: cell.value=10.1
<Cell Sheet.B5>: cell.value=7.7
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***

Comment: How can I get the data of `Sheet1` only?

Comment: I need data of a specific column but all rows. Lets say I need only 2nd column values of whole document.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('----------/dataset.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active
row_count = sheet.max_row
for i in range(row_count):
   print(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)
```

Comment: row and column names should start with 1 and this solution will read every cell and column in the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

This code will read a sheet as if it was a CSV and populate a list of dictionaries in `result` using the first row as the column titles.

```
        from openpyxl import load_workbook

        result = []
        wb = load_workbook(filename=file_name)
        sheet = wb.active
        col_count = sheet.max_column
        column_names = {}
        for c in range(1, col_count):
            heading = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
            if not heading:
                col_count = c
                break
            column_names[c] = heading

        for r, row_cells in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(2), 2):
            row = {}
            for c in range(1, col_count):
                value = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
                if type(value) == datetime:
                    value = value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                row[column_names[c]] = value
            result.append(row)
```