# Counting rows in Excel file but not empty rows (Python)

Tags: python, excel, count, row

So I have an Excel document where I have a lot different stuff. But I need some way to count all elements/rows that are NOT blank. The reason I just don't remove the blank rows from the Excel document is due to some ID trouble when I use it on my website. So whenever I need to delete something in the document I delete the text in the rows, but not the row itself.

Before I put it online, and just deleted the row entirely I could just use the following command to count how many elements/rows there were:

```
import openpyxl
from collections import Counter

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('document.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')    

number_of_rows = sheet.max_row
```

But as stated, now, since I put it online, I can only delete the text, and not the row, which gives me the same count if I use the above row, as if they were filled with text. So basically, how do I go about counting ONLY the rows that actually have some data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `iterate` over all `rows`, decided which `row` is not empty and count `not_empty +=1`.
Read [Iteration over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iteration-over-worksheets-rows-columns)