# How to pass arguments from excel column to python user defined function and loop every rows?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, arguments, openpyxl

I am trying to import data from Excel and loop each dataset.
I have data in column A, B, C of Excel sheet. 
I use openpyxl to import Data from excel workbook. But i don't know the way to refer column A,B,C are arguments for my function.
Please see the image:

[image: Sample Image]

And this is my function:

```
x = 0.2
def quadratic(a, b, c, x):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c
```

I want to pass data of Column A, B, C for arguments a, b, c and loop through every row (in my image, each row from row 2 to 18).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iteration over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iteration-over-worksheets-rows-columns)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a column D containing an Excel formula calculating exactly that, so you only have to retrieve one value? Did the above comment from stovfl fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Call quadratic function in excel using xlwings and then select 1row * 3columns (to get value of a,b,c) in excel. (please save python and excel fine at same location)

```
import xlwings as xw
@xw.func 
@xw.arg('num',ndim = 1) 
def quadratic(num):
    x = 0.2
    a=int(num[0])
    b=int(num[1])
    c=int(num[2])
    total = a*x**2 + b*x + c
    return total
```

Answer (score -1):

You can export the data in your spreadsheet as a CSV, and use python builtin csv module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to go through it line by line.

The following code adapted from the example in the doc should work, but I did not run it.
It reads the csv line by line, casts the values to floats, and calls your function

```
import csv

x = 0.2
def quadratic(a, b, c, x):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c

with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in datareader:
        data = map(float,row)
        print(quadratic(*data,x))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I don't want to use separate csv file. So i use openpyxl to import data from my excel work book. My problem is that no idea how to refere column A,B,C is the variable argument for my function.