# How to replace rows in Excel using Python with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code that will replace a row in a spreadsheet with the row below it if certain conditions are met, but receive the following error.  Is there an easy way to replace rows or do I have to go cell by cell?

```
import re
import openpyxl as xw
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = xw.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Gavin\Desktop\fair3.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet() 

n = 1
b = 1
while n < 200:
    cell = 'D' + str(n)
    def row(p):
        rowa = 'A' + str(p) + ":D" + str(p)
        return rowa

    if "Engineering" or "Energy" not in cell:
        sheet[row(n)] = sheet[row(n+b)]
        b += 1
    else:
        n += 1
```

but catch the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Gavin/Desktop/fair 2.py", line 45, in <module>
   sheet[row(n)] = sheet[row(n+b)]
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 380, in __setitem__
    self[key].value = value
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells

Comment: I think "engineering" in D1 makes no sense.You probably would like to check "engineering" in sheet["D1"]

Comment: Read How To iterate a Worksheet: [Iteration over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977775/7414759)