# Iterating through top row of excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have the following section of code which is using openpyxl to search through the top row of a spreadsheet and find the first element that does not contain a value. It returns the following error when I run it. Is there a better way to do this? Or how do I get rid of the error?

```
val = "something"
j = 1
titleIndex = None
while val != None:
    val = lecture['%s1' % chr(ord('@') + j)].internal_value
    print val
    print j
    j += 1
else:
    titleIndex = '%s1' % chr(ord('@') + j - 1)
```

> File "C:\Users\ecustodio\Documents\Python Scripts\ExcelIterate.py",
>   line 14, in set_title
>       val = lecture['%s1' % chr(ord('A') + j)].internal_value   File "C:\Users\ecustodio\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py",
>   line 345, in **getitem**
>       min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)   File "C:\Users\ecustodio\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py",
>   line 135, in range_boundaries
>       raise ValueError("{0} is not a valid coordinate or range") ValueError: {0} is not a valid coordinate or range

Comment: the line the traceback is referencing is 5th line of code

Comment: Use `ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1)` or `ws[1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the line

```
val = lecture['%s1' % chr(ord('A') + j)].internal_value
```

provided in the error message differs from the one in the code:

```
val = lecture['%s1' % chr(ord('@') + j)].internal_value
```

Please, check the value of `'%s1' % chr(ord('@') + j)` or whatever before requesting the item from `lecture`. And be sure that your `lecture` is really an existing worksheet.