# Python loop through Excel rows using Openpyxl, updating cells based on a transaction ID

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to write a scipt that can update a column based on a transaction ID. Im using Python3, Openpyxl to read the excel file

[image]

In the above image, it would be to update the highlighted cells with the same value in column K, as they have the same transaction ID in column C. Then when it gets to C12, it updates column K with a different value as the value of C has changed...and so on and so on.

So far I have:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
import re

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'Testing.xlsx')
ws = wb['Test']

for r in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
    column_c = ws.cell(row = r, column = 3).value
    column_h = ws.cell(row = r, column = 8).value
    column_i = ws.cell(row = r, column = 9).value
    column_j = ws.cell(row = r, column = 10).value

previous = None
while (previous == column_c):
    ws.cell(row = r, column = 11).value = column_j_formatted
    if (previous != column_c):
        continue

wb.save('Testing_processed.xlsx')
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to replace the while loop with:

```
previous_col_c = ws.cell(row=r-1, column=3)
for row_num in range (2, ws.max_row + 1):
    current_col_c = ws.cell(row=r, column=3)
    current_col_j = ws.cell(row=r, column=11)
    if current_col_c == previous_col_c:
        ws.cell(row = r, column = 11).value = column_j_formatted
    previous_col_c = current_col_c
```

Comment: Read [iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns/42977775?r=SearchResults&s=1|48.2225#42977775)

Comment: So, what problems do you have? BTW. This would be best done in a database.

Comment: @Charlie Clark I'm failing to make the while loop write to column J as desired. I tried it using mysql and php and it took forever to process 10000 lines

Comment: I think I might be onto something with the update there, I don't know if you can clearly see what im trying to implement

Comment: You should use `pandas` for this.

Comment: I've no idea why you'd use PHP at all for this. If you load everything into the DB in a single pass you can then just update the relevant rows.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate how the openpyxl API makes this kind of task very easy.

```
txn = None
filler = None
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
     a = row[0]
     k = row[10]
     if a.value != txn:
         txn = a.value
         filler = k.value
     if not k.value:
        k.value = filler
```

But really the work should be done in the source of the data, presumably a database.