# How to access columns using openpyxl in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to access a column from a workbook. Im able to do it using this:

```
for cell in sheet1["A"]:
    list.append(cell.value)
```

However, this collects all the value on the A column. What I need starts from A2 and on.
I this code:

```
for cell in sheet1["A2":"A"]
    list.append(cell.value)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: _What I need starts from A2 and on._ Do you know what the last row is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns)

Comment: @AMC the last row changes, it could be from 10 or 5.

Comment: @stovfl I'll take a look at that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

A super simple idea to fix your code is to use `len()` as in the following;

```
for cell in sheet1['A1':'A'+str(len(sheet['A']))]
    list.append(cell.value)
```

Remember that `str()` converts its argument to a string and `+` between two strings concatenates them. `len(sheet['A'])` returns the length of the column A.