# Inserting to certain columns in excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pip, openpyxl

using python package `openpyxl` I am trying to insert list items into a specific column `C`, as such `ws['C'].append([Column])`

doing it as so gives the error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`

Not really sure how to insert items in a specific column, on the sheet.

```
import sys 
from openpyxl import (load_workbook, Workbook)

try:
    def getExcel(spreadSheet):
        Columns=[]
        wb = load_workbook(spreadSheet)
        sheet = wb['sheet1']
        for cell in sheet['M']:
            if cell.value is not None: 
                Columns.append(cell.value)
            else: 
                continue
        print(len(Columns))
        wb = Workbook()
        dest_filename = 'new.xlsx'
        ws = wb.active
        for Column in Columns:
            ws['C'].append([Column])
        wb.save(dest_filename)
        print('Complete')

except ValueError:
    print ('failed...')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Updated, I think it was pretty clear, I am trying to insert list items in a specific column in this case C and its throwing the error as posted above.

Answer (score 0):

So after researching a bit, and seeing that it is possible to use numbers for the columns instead of letters, and seeing how cell() expects columns and row properties I was able to insert the items in the columns I wanted.

Incrementing `i` allowed the items to be inserting into every cell, in the same column.

```
i = 1 
for Column in Columns:
            ws.cell(row = i, column = 3).value = column
             i = i + 1
```

Comment: Read [iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns/42977775)