# Trying to find non-empty cells in a spreadsheet usin python and openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet with some empty and some nonempty cells.

I want to, for a set of rows and columns, print out the nonempty values and later copy those into a new spreadsheet into one column row by row one below the other...

Part of code:

```
sheet = book.active
cells = sheet['A1': 'B6']
for c1 in cells:
    if c1.value:
       print(c1.value)
```

It returns 'tuple has no attribute 'value'.

Why is that? How can I do this?

Comment: If a cell doesn't have a value, doesn't that mean it is empty?

Comment: Read [iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns/42977775)

Comment: @ScottHunter ***"If a cell doesn't have a value ..."***: `c1` is a `tuple` of `Cell` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `c1` in your code is not a cell, in fact it is a row. You can fix your code this way;

```
sheet=book.active
cells = sheet['A1':'B6']
for row in cells:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value:
            print(cell.value)
```