# Openpyxl: Iterating through a specific subset of Rows in a Single Column

Tags: python, openpyxl

Working on automating a data entry task and using openpyxl for the first time.

Need to iterate through a specific range of cells and input data ('B7' - 'B10').

Cannot figure out the right way to nest for loops to make this happen, and have not been able to use the docs to get it right. The below code snippet works, but it is pretty slapdash and have had to use this same strategy many other places in the program, worried about this causing bugs:

```
 for rowNumber in range(7,7+len(self.item_d)):
            self.sheet1['A'+ str(rowNumber)].value = next(iter_item_d_keys)
```

The pseudo-code would be something like this (though this is of course not possible):

`for row_cells in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2) in range(7, 7+len(self.item_d))`

Comment: Read [Iterate over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977775/7414759) with

Comment: You proablay want to combine iter_rows and offset. Nesting loops is generally not a good idea.