# How to append the same value down a column until it reaches the max row?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to pass a new value to the B column starting at B2 and looping to Max Row.

```
import openpyxl
import os

# Finds current directoryhow
current_path = os.getcwd()
print(current_path)

# Changes directory
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\satwood\\Documents\\Example')

# prints new current directory
new_path = os.getcwd()
print(new_path)

# load workbooks
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
type(wb)

# load worksheets
ws1 = wb.active

# append column B with cell_example

cell_example = ['success one']

max = ws1.max_row

for row, entry in enumerate(cell_example, start=1):
    ws1.cell(row=row + max, column=1, value=entry)

wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

The output that comes out of this code is:
None
None
None
None
None
None
...

Comment: Read [Iterate over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977775/7414759). You have to assign your value to `cell.value`.

Comment: @stovfl he is assigning a value via `ws1.cell(column=, row=, value=)` that isn't the issue, he is just iterating over a list that contains only `'success one'` so the loop runs once, and assign `'success one'` to the cell `A2`.

Comment: @DrorAv. correct, I would like it to write the same value in A2, A3, A4...until the max row. Eventually, I would write a function to pass to several columns in the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't doing what you are expecting it to do. You are iterating over `cell_example` which is a list with only 1 item (`'success one'`). Your loop runs once, row is equal `1+max_row` and entry is `success one` which is assigned to cell `A{1+max_row}`.

Do notice that B column is either `B` using `ws['B{row}']` or `2` using how you're using it in your code.

If you are trying to add the same value to all cells up to `max_row` in column B then you just need to change your loop to:

```
for row in range(2, max_row):
    ws1.cell(row=row, column=2, value=cell_example[0])
```

However, if you wish to iterate over the list in `cell_example` and assign those to column B then you can use:

```
for row, entry in enumerate(cell_example, start=2):
    ws1.cell(row=row, column=2, value=entry)
```

This will add items from the list `cell_example` into column B starting at the cell B2.

Do notice what stovfl said and pointed to that a better approach to iterating over cells in a column will be to use:

```
for col_cells in worksheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=2):
    for cell in col_cells:
        cell.value = "Something"
```

as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977775/7414759) which he metioned.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. This explains it well, and the code works.