# Need help creating a loop that will go through row by row in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, openpyxl

I'm a beginner at Python, and I have been trying my hand at some projects. I have an excel spreadsheet that contains a column of URLs that I want to open, pull some data from, output to a different column on my spreadsheet, and then go down to the next URL and repeat.

I was able to write code that allowed me to complete almost the entire process if I enter in a single URL, but I suck at creating loops

My list is only 10 cells long.

My question is, what code can I use that will loop through a column until it hits a stopping point. .

```
import urllib.request, csv, pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xl = pd.ExcelFile("filename.xlsx")
ws = xl.parse("Sheet1")
i = 0 # This is where I insert the row number for a specific URL

urlpage = str(ws['URLPage'][i]) # 'URLPage' is the name of the column in Excel
p = urlpage.replace(" ", "") # This line is for deleting whitespace in my URL
response = urllib.request.urlopen(p)
```

Also as stated, I'm newer at Python, so if you see where I can improve the code I already have, please let me know.

Comment: Hi @Pax - welcome to stack overflow! This question has multiple parts, and it looks like you've already solved several of them! In order to get the best quality answers on this site, it's best to ask very specific questions, limited in their scope and examples to specific, targeted questions. See these posts on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Feel free to modify your question to fit these guidelines :)

Comment: Hi @Pax, welcome, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns/42977775#42977775) it should aid you with what you are trying to do.

Also you should always try and find if a question has been answered before prior to asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns)