# Force pandas.to_excel to write data as 'Text' instead 'General' format

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, pandas.excelwriter

I've already set cell format as 'Text' in the target Excel column. However pandas.to_excel changes the format to 'General' when writing strings to this column, eventually the column ends up with blank cells are formatted as 'Text' and non-blank ones as 'General'. Is there a way to write data as 'Text' instead of 'General'?

```
def exportData(df, dstfile, sheet):
    book = load_workbook(dstfile)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(dstfile, engine='openpyxl', date_format='dd/mm/yyyy', datetime_format='mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    df.to_excel(writer, header=False, startrow=2, index=False, sheet_name=sheet)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Did you try using `set_column` like [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html)?

Comment: This link is using xlsxwriter but I am using openpyxl because as for as I know xlsxwriter cannot write to existing sheets

Comment: @KhalidAmin If you set the cell format to `@` it will be set as text. you can iterate over the cells after youre done writing them using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns/42977775#42977775) and setting the cell format as such `cell.number_format = '@'`. This will cause the cells to have a `TEXT` formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the cells using the [following method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns/42977775#42977775).

The cells you want to format as `TEXT` just use:

```
cell.number_format = '@'
```

This will set the cell formatting as `TEXT` in Excel.

There might be a way to do it straight from the `ExcelWriter` within Pandas but I'm unfarmiliar with it, maybe someone who knows better will edit the answer for that option as well.

Comment: This worked thanks, although I'd prefer not to iterate over every cell but I couldn't find a better solution

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to save data in pandas as `'object'` (which is text) like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, dtype=object)
```

and after that if you export to Excel with pandas `to_excel` method it will be stored in Excel as text.

Comment: Give that man a medal! This should be the solution!

Comment: This saves the data in Excel in the "Gerneral" format and not in the "Text" format (OP requestest "Text" format).

Comment: This is the text format: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html store it any way you like with dtype=..

Comment: This answer is definitely wrong. OP asked for *“Text”* number format in Excel, not in pandas, `dtype` in pandas is not the point. For a solution, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77668598/13968392).

Answer (score 0):

One can use the follwoing code to apply a number format (Excel terminology) in Excel to the exported pandas object. Instead of the *"General"* number format, which is used by default in Excel for exported pandas objects, one can specify the *"Text"* number format. Using the *"Text"* number format also prevents that [numbers change to dates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8) when entering the "editing" mode (shortcut `F2` in excel) and then pressing `Enter`. As of the date of this answer, the following code seems to be the shortest way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["23-3", "21-1"],
                   ["8-5", "6-7"]], columns=["A", "B"])

# @ is the number format code of Excel for the "Text" number format.
df.style.map(lambda v: "number-format: @").to_excel(r"test.xlsx")
```

The credit for the last line of code should go to the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html).