# How to move cell range in openpyxl with its properties (hyperlinks, formatting etc.)?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to create a script to move some (or all) cells. This is my code idea but I don't know how to implement the last line (example for moving 5 cells right):

```
new_rows = []
for row in ws.rows:
    new_rows.append((None,) * 5 + row)
ws.rows = new_rows
```

Comment: What do you mean by move cell range?

Comment: I mean to programatically achieve the same as 1. cut cells 2. paste them (with all atributes) 5 columns to the right

Comment: I found some complicated solution for inserting rows on bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/snippets/openpyxl/qyzKn) but it is both ugly and not operating od columns but rows.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's hard for me to follow. You want copy value and style from `A1` and copy it in `A2` through `A6`(cells are chosen for example)?

Comment: Sorry for not communicating clearly. Example: I want to move range A1:B2 to F1:G2 with styles and other attribs.

Comment: So if we are talking about Excel internal language what you want to do is _"Copy formatting from one location and apply it to another"_?

Comment: I want to copy values, formatting, conditional formatting, hyperlinks, and merged ranges.

Comment: Relevant: [Copying styles from a range to another range?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42761839/7414759)

Comment: Thanks! From all this answers I see that there isn't any short way to copy all cell as you would do in excel's ctr+c/ctr+v.

Answer (score 5):

You can also move ranges of cells within a worksheet using "move_range".

This will move the cells in the range A8:Z8 up one row, and right two columns.

`ws.move_range("A8:Z8", rows=-1, cols=2)`

If cells contain formulae you can add "translate=True"

`ws.move_range("A8:Z8", rows=-1, cols=2, translate=True)`

You can also add formatting after the move.

```
    for cell in col:
        cell.number_format = '0%'
```

This transforms the cell value to a percentage value.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

After long days of researching I figured out there is no easy and pretty way to copy cell range with all attributes. You need to iterate through the range and for each cell copy value and every attrib separately. Sample function to copy single cell would look this way:

```
ws.cell(row=to_row, column=to_col).value = ws.cell(row=from_row, column=from_col).value
from_style = ws.cell(row=from_row, column=from_col)._style
ws.cell(row=to_row, column=to_col)._style = from_style
ws.cell(row=to_row, column=to_col).hyperlink = ws.cell(row=from_row, column=from_col).hyperlink
ws.cell(row=to_row, column=to_col).number_format = ws.cell(row=from_row, column=from_col).number_format
```